# Scala main actor not matching cases in react block

Tags: scala, actor

The cases in the act method of the main actor are never matched in this code, so my wrapUp method is never called.

```
import java.net.Socket
import scala.actors._
import Actor._
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

object LowPortScanner {

  var lastPort = 0
  var openPorts = ArrayBuffer[Int]()
  var longestRunTime = 00.00
  var results = List[Tuple3[Int, Range, Long]]()

  val host = "localhost"
  val numProcs = 1 to Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()
  val portsPerProc = 1024 / numProcs.size
  val caller = self
  val procPortRanges = numProcs.foldLeft(List[Tuple2[Int, Range]]()) { (portRanges, proc) =>
    val tuple2 = (proc.toInt, (lastPort + 1) to (lastPort + portsPerProc))
    lastPort += portsPerProc
    tuple2 :: portRanges
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    //spawn an actor for each processor that scans a given port range
    procPortRanges.foreach { proc =>
      actor {
        caller ! scan(proc._1, proc._2)
      } //end inner actors
    } //end numProcs.foreach  

    //catch results from the processor actors above
    def act {
      loop {
        reactWithin(100) {
          //update the list of results returned from scan
          case scanResult: Tuple3[Int, Range, Long] =>
            println("Processor " + scanResult._1 + " completed scan of ports " + scanResult._2.first + " through " + scanResult._2.last)
            results = results ::: List(scanResult)

          //check if results have been returned for each actor
          case TIMEOUT =>
            println("Main actor timed out")
            if (results.size == numProcs.size) wrapUp

          case _ =>
            println("got back something weird from one of the port scan actors!")
            wrapUp
        }
      }
    }    

    //Attempt to open a socket on each port in the given range
    //returns a Tuple3[procID: Int, ports: Range, time: Long
    def scan(proc: Int, ports: Range) = {
      val startTime = System.nanoTime()
      ports.foreach { n =>
        try {
          //println("Processor " + proc + " is checking port " + n)
          print(".")

          val socket = new Socket(host, n)

          //println("Found open port: " + n)
          openPorts += n

          socket.close
        } catch {
          case e: Exception =>
          //println("While scanning port " + n + " caught Exception: " + e)
        }
      }
      (proc, ports, startTime - System.nanoTime())
    }

    //output results and kill the main actor
    def wrapUp {
      println("These are the open ports in the range 1-1024:")
      openPorts.foreach { port => println(port) }
      results.foreach { result => if (result._3 > longestRunTime) { longestRunTime = result._3 } }
      println("Time to scan ports 1 through 1024 is: %3.3f".format(longestRunTime / 1000))
      caller ! exit
    }
  }
}
```

The code that spawns off the actors for each processor works fine, the scan method is invoked correctly for each range of ports, and I have confirmed that exactly 1024 ports are scanned.
My expectation is that the line :

```
caller ! scan(proc._1, proc._2)
```

should send a message containing (Int, Range, Long) back to the main actor.  The main actor's act method should then catch that message and execute:

```
          case scanResult: Tuple3[Int, Range, Long] =>
            println("Processor " + scanResult._1 + " completed scan of ports " + scanResult._2.first + " through " + scanResult._2.last)
            results = results ::: List(scanResult)
```

This is not happening, however.  In fact, as far as I can tell, none of my messages are coming back to the main actor.  I'm not clear on what I'm missing or doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem as you note is that the message being sent are not being received. This is because the actor created with `actor {caller ! scan(proc._1, proc._2)}` does not have an `act` definition associated with it. The `def act{...}` method has nothing to do with the actor created since it is a method on `LowPortScanner` and not an actor.

Maintaining the spirit of your code you can define the body to be executed by the actor within the  `actor{...}` and assign it to a value and send it messages.

```
 //spawn an actor for each processor that scans a given port range
 procPortRanges.foreach { proc =>
   val myactor = actor {
     //catch results from the processor actors above
       loop {
         reactWithin(100) {
         //update the list of results returned from scan
         case scanResult: Tuple3[Int, Range, Long] =>
           println("Processor " + scanResult._1 + " completed scan of ports " + scanResult._2.first + " through " + scanResult._2.last)
           results = results ::: List(scanResult)

         //check if results have been returned for each actor
         case TIMEOUT =>
           println("Main actor timed out")
           if (results.size == numProcs.size) wrapUp

         case _ =>
           println("got back something weird from one of the port scan actors!")
           wrapUp
        }
      }
     //catch results from the processor actors above
   } //end inner actors
     myactor ! scan(proc._1, proc._2)
 } //end numProcs.foreach
```

Another way to do it is to extend the Actor trait. This way the `def act{...}` will handle messages received by the `LowPortScanner` actor. I also did some minor refactoring including using `this` instead of `self`. The Actor also had to be started with `this.start()`.

```
import java.net.Socket
import scala.actors._
import Actor._
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

object LowPortScanner extends Actor {

  var lastPort = 0
  var openPorts = ArrayBuffer[Int]()
  var longestRunTime = 00.00
  var results = List[Tuple3[Int, Range, Long]]()

  val host = "localhost"
  val numProcs = 1 to Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()
  val portsPerProc = 1024 / numProcs.size

  val procPortRanges = numProcs.foldLeft(List[Tuple2[Int, Range]]()) { (portRanges, proc) =>
    val tuple2 = (proc.toInt, (lastPort + 1) to (lastPort + portsPerProc))
    lastPort += portsPerProc
    tuple2 :: portRanges
  }
    //catch results from the processor actors above
    def act {
      loop {
        reactWithin(100) {
          //update the list of results returned from scan
          case scanResult: Tuple3[Int, Range, Long] =>
            println("Processor " + scanResult._1 + " completed scan of ports " + scanResult._2.first + " through " + scanResult._2.last)
            results = results ::: List(scanResult)

          //check if results have been returned for each actor
          case TIMEOUT =>
            println("Main actor timed out")
            if (results.size == numProcs.size) wrapUp

          case _ =>
            println("got back something weird from one of the port scan actors!")
            wrapUp
        }
      }
    }

    //Attempt to open a socket on each port in the given range
    //returns a Tuple3[procID: Int, ports: Range, time: Long
    def scan(proc: Int, ports: Range) = {
      val startTime = System.nanoTime()
      ports.foreach { n =>
        try {
          //println("Processor " + proc + " is checking port " + n)
          print(".")

          val socket = new Socket(host, n)

          //println("Found open port: " + n)
          openPorts += n

          socket.close
        } catch {
          case e: Exception =>
          //println("While scanning port " + n + " caught Exception: " + e)
        }
      }
      (proc, ports, startTime - System.nanoTime())
    }

    //output results and kill the main actor
    def wrapUp {
      println("These are the open ports in the range 1-1024:")
      openPorts.foreach { port => println(port) }
      results.foreach { result => if (result._3 > longestRunTime) { longestRunTime = result._3 } }
      println("Time to scan ports 1 through 1024 is: %3.3f".format(longestRunTime / 1000))
      this ! exit
    }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    //spawn an actor for each processor that scans a given port range
    this.start()
    procPortRanges.foreach { proc =>
      actor {
        this ! scan(proc._1, proc._2)
      } //end inner actors
    } //end numProcs.foreach  
  }

}
```

Here are the results from a run:

```
scala> LowPortScanner.main(Array[String]())

scala> ...Processor 6 completed scan of ports 641 through 768
...Processor 5 completed scan of ports 513 through 640
...Processor 4 completed scan of ports 385 through 512
...Processor 3 completed scan of ports 257 through 384
...Processor 1 completed scan of ports 1 through 128
...Processor 7 completed scan of ports 769 through 896
...Processor 2 completed scan of ports 129 through 256
...Processor 8 completed scan of ports 897 through 1024
Main actor timed out
These are the open ports in the range 1-1024:
139
22
445
591
631
111
Time to scan ports 1 through 1024 is: 0.000


scala> LowPortScanner.results
res2: List[(Int, Range, Long)] = List((6,Range(641, 642, 643,...
```

Comment: This is possibly the most concise and helpful answer I've received since beginning to use Stack Overflow. Thanks! Your second example is very illuminating and helped me identify some key gaps in my understanding of using actors and passing messages.  I also fixed time display bug.